# Jobs for a multimedia major

Tags: art

Let me start by saying I only have the option of obtaining an associate's in this major. My local colleges do not have a 4 year degree available for this major.

My question is, what are some realistic choices i have for employment after completing this degree? Ive come up with being a media coordinator (social media) but thats all i can come up with. I need something to search for besides 'multimedia jobs' is what im trying to say. What are my options here? Is a 4 year absolutely imperative? This major is right up my alley but Im short of ideas for actual employment.

Edit: the curriculum is as follows
2 dimensional design, 
Color theory, 
Drawing 1, 
Photography 1, 
Graphic design 1, 
Web design 1, 
Video editing 1, 
Computer animation 1

Comment: This is quite a broad question... You could be a videographer, photographer, manager, musician, poet, etc.

Comment: Depends heavily on what you make out of it and what the individual classes you take. More importantly it depends on what you make out of it. Multimedia also has a halo effect so it attracts a lot of people but the job prospects vary greatly.

Comment: Daniel, please [edit] your question to give some specifics about your program. Right now this is overly broad and brainstorming. Once edited we can reopen it if its something that can be answered.

Comment: Ok thanks ryan. Ive just edited the post now.

Comment: The college career services office may be able to answer this question for you.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the world lives in a post career era*. No education is going to give you a job directly, not as such. See, many of the jobs 5-10 years from now do not even exists yet or are so niche that they are under the radar.

For some perspective. Back when i was going for secondary education the internet was not considered to be anything. We had to form a nonprofit organization just to be able to get internet dial ups because that was something only for companies. We were ahead of the curve, but only a handful of us. By the time I hit University 3 years later it had become the biggest growing sector.

What a good education does is it tries to give you the tools to train yourself to the specific task at hand. Bad education is just training to do something, unfortunately students tend to concentrate on training.

Now for the bad news, multimedia attracts lot of people. Its very competitive and your competing with guys that are already deeply into multimedia, they have a head start. So your really looking for connections as much as a education and basic training to get ahead. For this reason its a potential dead end. But we dont know what the situation is in your area. Look for a rounded education that lets you move into new things. Also unfortunately quite often these jobs are freelance in nature, so be prepared to work for almost no money for the love of your craft in the early days or possibly all days. I'm not sating on can not succeed but its by no mean the easiest paths.

Is 4 a year degree imperative? No, no education is, but these schools tend to have a better alumni and give more contacts. The courses your given do not really tell much about the quality. Looks more like a bare bones minimum training to me. One really needs 3 years of drawing classes for example, and one really needs a few years on animation too if drawing and animating is something you want to pursue.

* Unless you chooses medical school, teacher school or say nursing.